# ReactNative not recorded in setState from useEffect

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, fetch

I'm trying to execute a request from useEffect but for some reason, it is not written to useState. If I output to the console, then I get the data, but I can’t get the data from useState. Please tell me how to solve it.

```
const [orderAttributes, setOrderAttributes] = useState();
const [orderIncluded, setOrderIncluded] = useState();

useEffect(() => {

const getOrdersData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    'https://demo.org/api/v2/storefront/account/orders?include=variants.images',
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
    },
  );
  const content = await response.json();
  console.log(content); //response data presented
  setOrderAttributes(content.data);
  setOrderIncluded(content.included);
};
console.log(orderAttributes); //data is't presented
}, []);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your function is async, so it will not block the execution of the console log. If you want to react to changes in the state values, write another useEffect with the state variables in the dependency array.